# If data is undefined, at least one attribute must be present pubsub

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to use Google Cloud's Pub/Sub API to send messages to topic subscribers, but I'm having a problem where it's returning the message "**If data is undefined, at least one attribute must be present.**". I'm going to use it with Cloud Functions. I have the following code which is the same as the official Pub/Sub NodeJS documentation with minor changes:

```
exports.helloWorld = async (req, res) => {

    const parse = require('url-parse');
    const punycode = require('punycode');
    const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');

    let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';

    let referHeader = req.headers.referer;
    let userIP = req.socket.remoteAddress;
    let originHeader = req.headers.origin;
    let userAgenteHeader = req.useragent;
    let a = req.query.a;
    let s = req.query.s;
    let e = req.query.e;

    try {
        
        const pubSubClient = new PubSub({
            project_id: 'my-project',
            credentials: {
                private_key: "my_private_key",
                client_email: 'email_project@myemail.com',
            }
        });

        a = 123; //Change for test
            
        let topicNameOrId = 'MY_TOPIC_ID';

        const data = JSON.stringify({
            "data": "analytics",
            "attributes": {
              "a": a
            }
          });

        const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data);

        const messageId = await pubSubClient
          .topic(topicNameOrId)
          .publishMessage(dataBuffer);

        res.status(200).send(`Message ${messageId} published.`);

      } catch (error) {

        console.error();
        res.status(403).send(`${error.message}`);

        process.exitCode = 1;
      }
};
```

I've tried to do it with JSON.stringify, without it, directly in the function, but nothing worked, it always gives the same error and I'm passing the data parameter normally.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to this one, but I was scratching my head why this wasn't working.   Since `.publish` has been deprecated, it isn't a viable solution anymore.

The documentation threw us this curveball:

```
const data = Buffer.from('Hello, world!');

const callback = (err, messageId) => {
  if (err) {
    // Error handling omitted.
  }
};

topic.publishMessage({data}, callback);
```

Basically what `{data}` means here is `{data: data}`, therefore it's important to have the key named `data`

Changing the publishMessage line should fix it.

```
const messageId = await pubSubClient.topic(topicNameOrId).publishMessage({data: dataBuffer});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I was able to reproduce your error. After debugging your code, it was stuck when it uses `publishMessage()`. Apparently [publishMessage()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/latest/pubsub/topic#_google_cloud_pubsub_Topic_publishMessage_member_1_) accepts a **message object**.

> publishMessage(message: MessageOptions): Promise<[string]>;

Use [publish()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/latest/pubsub/topic#_google_cloud_pubsub_Topic_publish_member_1_) instead, it accepts **buffer object**.

> publish(data: Buffer, attributes?: Attributes): Promise;

Apply publish() in your code, use the fix below:

```
const messageId = await pubSubClient.topic(topicNameOrId).publish(dataBuffer);
```

Cloud Function output:

[image]

Actual Pubsub message:

[image]